# I'm getting an error that says IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to python and trying to figure out where in my code i'm making the index 0? how should I fix it to resolve the code and show the 50 related movies to "Avatar". I know the error is probably in my "get_index_from_title" function but I am not sure how to resolve it.

```
def get_title_from_index(index):
  return df[df.index == index]["title"].values[0]

def get_index_from_title(title):
  return df[df.title == title]["index"].values[0] 
##################################################


# Step 1. Read CSV File

df = pd.read_csv("movies.csv",quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False)

#Step2: Select Features
features = ['keywords', 'cast','genres','director']

#Step 3: Create a solumn in DF which combines all selected features
for feature in features:
  df[feature] = df[feature].fillna('')


def combine_features(row):
  try:
    return row['keywords'] +" "+row['cast']+" "+row["genres"] +" "+row["director"] 
  except:
    print("Error:", row)

df["combined_features"] = df.apply(combine_features,axis=1)

# print("Combined Features:", df["combine_features"].head())

#Step 4: Create count matrix from this new combined column

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(df["combined_features"])


#Step 5: Compute the Cpsine Similarity based on the count_matrix

cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
movie_user_likes = "Avatar"

#Step 6: Get index of this movie from its title
movie_index = get_index_from_title(movie_user_likes)

similar_movies = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[movie_index]))


#Step 7: Get a list of similar movies in dscending order of similarity score 

sorted_similar_movies = sorted(similar_movies, key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)


#Step8: Print title of first 50 movies
i = 0
for movie in sorted_similar_movies:
  print (get_title_from_index(movie[0]))
  i= i+1
  if i>50:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
def get_title_from_index(index):
  return df.loc[index, "title"]

def get_index_from_title(title):
  return df.loc[df.title == title].index[0]
```

This is the proper way of selecting a value from a dataframe given an index and column.